# How can I fix dumped inserts starting with comma?

Tags: mysql

How can I fix dumped inserts starting with comma ?

In my case when I dump my database to file with following command:
`mysqldump --databases test -u username --password=password > dump.sql`

for some dumped tables I get inserts starting with comma instead of a value. How can I fix it ? What maybe the reason ?

### mysqldump  Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.7.20, for Linux (x86_64)

### mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

```
LOCK TABLES `exaple` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `exaple` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `exaple` (`document`) VALUES (,'{\"id\": \"28d0cacd-76e5-4036-ac22-4db28c0495b0\"}')
```

It is always when the next column is `JSON` type, and the table has generated columns.

Comment: do a string replace (, to ( in dump.

Comment: I do not want to edit the dump, what i need is to get the correct output and not to fix it.

Comment: Anyway I already found the solution, this thing happens if in your table schema generated columns are declared before the document column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thing happens if in your table schema generated columns are declared before the document column. The fix was simple to move them below.

## Before

```
CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `id`        CHAR(36) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (document->>'$.id') STORED NOT NULL,
  `document`  JSON                                                    NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8
  COLLATE = utf8_bin;
```

## After

```
CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `document`  JSON                                                    NOT NULL,
  `id`        CHAR(36) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (document->>'$.id') STORED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8
  COLLATE = utf8_bin;
```